# How to disable header view in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Anybody knows how to disable the header view in list view?
I need to add a header into a list view and make it not clickable.
For adapter it's pretty simple: return false in `isEnabled(int position)` method but I didn't find an appropriate function for list headers/footers. Setting enabled flag for header view didn't help, nor did specifying "android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"" in header's xml

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use these methods to add header and footer in list:

```
list.addFooterView(v);
list.addHeaderView(v, data, isSelectable);
```

Comment: I was using the single argument method with just list.addHeaderView(v).  Using this answer, setting data to null worked.